# Why doesn't startActivityForResult() lead to onActivityResult() execution?

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

Still trying to make my screen record app. I keep on working with MediaRecorder, as I was told some time ago, so I got stuck with another problem.

I just need to initialize a MediaProjection object to make my code work, that's what I do in onActivityResult(), as it's written in [this guide](https://www.fandroid.info/kak-sozdat-prilozhenie-dlya-zapisi-ekrana-android-smartfona/):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECORD_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        screenRecorder.setMediaProject(mediaProjection);
    }
}
```

The setMediaProjection() looks like

```
public void setMediaProject(MediaProjection project) {
    mediaProjection = project;
}
```

, so it shouldnt't cause any trouble.

And that's how I try to call onActivityResult():

```
/* start transmission */
        if(screenRecorder.isRunning()) {
            screenRecorder.stopRecord();
        } else {
            Intent captureIntent = mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
            startActivityForResult(captureIntent, RECORD_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
```

The fun and crazy thing is that when I first launched the debug, it worked! After startActivityForResult() I got to onActivityResult() and initialized mediaProjection: my phone showed me a dialog window whether I allow to capture the screen or not, so I allowed that and got a special symbol (smth like  screen with displayed waves) at my status bar.

But a few moments later I found an issue when stopping the record and restarted the debug session to trace it more exactly. After that onActivityResult() is just ignored: startActivityForResult() is called, the dialog window is shown, but after allowing the record onActivityResult() is completely skipped and mediaProjection is null. The restarting and re-installing the apk with the same code didn't fix anything.

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you calling `startActivityForResult` from a fragment or activity?

Comment: I have no fragments in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a very simple solution. I just initialized the record service that put null into mediaRecorder's mediaProjection, so after that I was unable to re-initialize it. Putting intent which called onActivivtyResult() into activity's onCreate() before starting the service fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Your onActivityResult only does something when the result code is OK, try this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECORD_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        screenRecorder.setMediaProject(mediaProjection);
    } else { 
      //TODO: Do something 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Result code is not RESULT_OK, ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply, but that didn't change anything really. I placed a breakpoint at the 1st "if" of the function, and it was just ignored. The debugger made a first stop at the next breakpoint that's even in another class.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. This could bu about threading. In my project I started an activity and opening activity try to start chrome intent. Chrome is opening in debug mode but not opened real mode.
I added a delay when opening chrome

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startAuth();
        }
    }, 100);
```